# can video adapters output digital video through their VGA output?

Tags: video, graphics-card, vga, dvi, adapter

Some video adapters have both [DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) and [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) outputs. For a two screen configuration I could attach a [VGA to DVI adapter](https://www.google.com/search?q=vga%20to%20dvi%20adapter&tbm=isch) to the VGA output, and have both screens attached with a DVI cable.

Would the video adapter detect this and transmit digital video instead of analog?
Does it depend on the specific video adapter model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there are two ways to do that:

1. **VGA to DVI Adapter**: With a simple VGA to DVI Adapter, **BUT the signal will not be digital**! Because the DVI specification contains also wires for the analog signal, there are plenty of simple adapter for just some dollars. So if your Screen is able to use these analog signals on the DVI cable it may work. But remember you then have a DVI-A (analog)
2. **VGA to DVI Converter:** There are external active converters of analog to real digital signal, but they are a bit more expensive. Then you would have a real DVI-D (digital) signal.

Maybe read the good [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) explaining the basic technical details.

Comment: The converter will not improve on the loss of video quality due to using VGA analogue signals, but it may prevent the "shadow effect" sometimes visible when using a VGA analogue signal throughout the cable to the screen

Answer (score 1):

No.  VGA only outputs the video signal as Analog only.